# Change Sharepoint site footer font size

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I have sharepoint online(2019) where I am trying o change the footer font size, but there's no option available to change font size.

Can anyone guide me achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you mention about modern view(2019), you need create custom [SPFx application customizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/build-a-hello-world-extension) so you could inject custom CSS to override SharePoint CSS.

You could check below [github demo sp-dev-fx-extensions](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-extensions/tree/master/samples/react-application-injectcss)